# HTML-PD4ML Java

Tags: java, dependency-management, pd4ml

I  trying to convert Html to pdf using pd4ml.  Loaded pd4ml.jar in lib folder.  I am getting the error

> Error. ss_css2.jar is not in the classpath.

Is there any other jar I have to download?

My code is :

```java
private void runConverter(String url, String outputPath)
        throws InvalidParameterException, MalformedURLException, IOException {  
    File output = new File(outputPath);  
    java.io.FileOutputStream fos = new java.io.FileOutputStream(output);  

    PD4ML pd4ml = new PD4ML();  

    pd4ml.setHtmlWidth(userSpaceWidth); // set frame width of "virtual web browser"   

    // choose target paper format and "rotate" it to landscape orientation  
    pd4ml.setPageSize(pd4ml.changePageOrientation(PD4Constants.A4));   

    // define PDF page margins  
    pd4ml.setPageInsetsMM(new Insets(topValue, leftValue, bottomValue, rightValue));   

    // source HTML document also may have margins, could be suppressed this way   
    // (PD4ML *Pro* feature):  
    pd4ml.addStyle("BODY {margin: 0}", true);  

    // If built-in basic PDF fonts are not sufficient or   
    // if you need to output non-Latin texts,  
    // TTF embedding feature should help (PD4ML *Pro*)  
    pd4ml.useTTF("c:/windows/fonts", true);  

    pd4ml.render(new URL(url), fos); // actual document conversion from URL to file  
    fos.close();  

    System.out.println( outputPath + "\ndone." );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add to classpath all jars on which depends pd4ml

More simple solution - start using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) or [gradle](/questions/tagged/gradle) to dependency management and add pd4ml as dependencies.

Or googled all required jars for pd4ml, or try to run and add jars one by one

> Pd4Cmd execution requires pd4ml.jar and ss_css2.jar are in the classpath.

(c) http://pd4ml.com/html-to-pdf-command-line-tool.htm